# Cypress - Entering values into and accepting prompts

Tags: cypress

The web application I am testing is set up behind an authentication wall like this whenever the URL is accessed. Is it possible to enter values into the fields in this prompt and confirming it using Cypress?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass this auth wall by using Cypress' `cy.visit -> auth` options. Also used the `failOnStatusCode: false` option to avoid Cypress failing test prematurely.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Arguments